# Tensorflow tutorial, convolution

Tags: tensorflow

So I have been looking a bit into Tensorflow and trying to get my head around one thing, i do not know what I am missing. I am checking out the tutorial from https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/layers and more particularly, from the model building step:

```
  """Model function for CNN."""
  # Input Layer
  input_layer = tf.reshape(features, [-1, 28, 28, 1])

  # Convolutional Layer #1
  conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(
      inputs=input_layer,
      filters=32,
      kernel_size=[5, 5],
      padding="same",
      activation=tf.nn.relu)

  # Pooling Layer #1
  pool1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv1, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2)

  # Convolutional Layer #2 and Pooling Layer #2
  conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(
      inputs=pool1,
      filters=64,
      kernel_size=[5, 5],
      padding="same",
      activation=tf.nn.relu)
  pool2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv2, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2)

  # Dense Layer
  pool2_flat = tf.reshape(pool2, [-1, 7 * 7 * 64])
```

If I understand it correctly, input convulated with 32 @ 5x5 filters creates an output of 32 feature maps @ 28x28. Then max-pooled reduces the feature maps to width and height = 14x14.

So here is the problem for me to understand, we have 32 @ 14x14 feature maps and we convolute with another set of 64 filters @ 5x5. Should it produce 32*64=2048 feature maps of size 14x14? So when reshaping it, we should use [-1,7*7*2048] after the last max-pooling step? Or is this convulation in conv2 done with a depth of 32, the filters are sized like [5,5,32]? Maybe I am missing some crucial theory or just blind ;>

Would appriacte if someone could help me understand this!

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using padding "same".

```
If padding == "same"
    output_shape[i] = ceil(input_shape[i]/stides[i])
If padding == "valid": 
    output_spatial_shape[i] = ceil((input_spatial_shape[i] - (spatial_filter_shape[i]-1) * dilation_rate[i]) / strides[i]).
```

To get the behavior you're expecting use padding "valid".

Look at API here : https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/convolution

I hope this helps.

Comment: Ah ok! So how does it work with padding = "same", it does convultion in regards to the depth of the previous feature maps?

Comment: It just kinda pad in the boundaries of the feature maps to get output shape.

Comment: Ye I know that, but after pool1, (in my head) we should have 32 feature maps of size 14x14 (or 14 by 14 and depth of 32). For a single filter in conv2 (assuming size 5x5) we should get 32 feature maps and if we pad it will stay the same size. Repeat for 64 filters and we have 2048 maps. But clearly it is not :(